# Figure out if two URLs navigate to the same page

Tags: url, networking, curl, request, server

**This is a hypothetical question. No codes whatsoever.**

Say that you should figure out if two URL's navigate to the same page. You have to do this programmatically. Just scanning through the URL is not enough, maybe one of them has an anchor link which navigates to the same page but different section. Or maybe there could be a ref=... on the url that is just used to monitor the referrers by the backend.

One possible solution could be requesting the contents of both URL's and comparing the HTML outcomes, but if you have to do this many times to many different URL's it is a costly operation. Could there be a better solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, by reading the HTTP response headers, which are sent by the server after each request.

When you're redirected, the server responds with the status code 302. 200 is the code when everything is OK and the most popular is the 404, not found.

Check this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) for a little more about the 302 status code and [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for the complete list.

Comment: As I make requests, I can only get 200 OK code. 302 Found is not present on the response headers. Either way, there is a "content-length" field which I could compare. That would be faster and more efficient.

Comment: And if the page is redirecting you through javascript, you can extract the URL from the body. And that would probably be a very specific implementation. There are many things you need to/can do, but it looks to me as an edge case that you'll need to study, with the resources you have at your disposal.